# How to specify Formatted NSString constants

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uikit, stringwithformat

I have some **predefined string** formats that I would like to fill values to, at runtime, and present to the user. I want to store them as either `constants` or `defines`, whichever suits better.

Something like:

```
@% has sent you a message on @%-@%-@%.
```

At runtime, above will get sender's name and mm-dd-yy to prepare required string:

```
James Bond has sent you a message on 12-31-2050.
```

Can anyone point to code to implement such kind of thing?

EDIT:
Contrary to what many (especially the downvoters!) believe:

This is not simply a [string formatting question](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943). It is posted to ensure:

- the string format storage is memory efficient (static vs define vs anything else) because I want to store the format permanently, not just for the time of usage
- the value substitution at runtime is time efficient (stringWithFormat vs other options)

Comment: Please check https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: The @%-@%-@% way of formatting the date will be horrible for localization

Comment: @MidhunMP, the question is more about having a constant rather than just the format. David, this format is just for sample. To whoever has downvoted, please specify reason. I see many potential users seeking this solution so unless there is a duplicate of this question deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

At top,

```
#define MESSAGE @"%@ has sent you a message on %@-%@-%@."
```

Then whenever you want to use that message, use below syntex:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:MESSAGE, <sender_name>, <date>, <month>, <year>];
```

sender_name,date,month,year are dynamic values.

Hope, you got an idea.

Happy Coding!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

try this.. May be it will help you.

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
     NSLog(@"theDate..%@",theDate);
    NSString *str = @"yourString";
    NSString *new =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ has sent you a message on %@", str, theDate];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ has sent you a message on %@", who, date]`

Comment: you will need NSDateFormatter for date, just %@ will not look nice

Answer (score 1):

fIrst of all,you need to get current date

```
NSDateFormatter *date= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [date setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    NSDate *thisDate= [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSString *currentDate= [date stringFromDate:thisDate];
 NSLog(@"Current date is..%@",currentDate);
```

Now you can enter any string at runtime

```
 NSString *strng = @"whatever kind of string which you want to add at runtime";
    NSString *newString=  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ has sent you a message on %@", strng, currentDate];
```

The value of "newString" will provide you the required result.

Answer (score 0):

Use
        #define messageString(x,y,z) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ has sent you a message on %@-%@-%@.",x,y,z]